# Reversing a string (or list) recursively

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a function in haskell that reverses lists recursively. I wrote a helper function that takes the original list and an empty list then transfers elements from the first one to the other in a LIFO pattern.

Here's what I have:

```
myreverse :: [a] -> [a]
myreverse list = myflip list []

myflip :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
myflip list1 newList
    | null list1        = newList
    | otherwise         = myflip (tail list1) ((head list1) : newList)
```

I know there's a built-in function that does it for me but the requirement is that I only use *head*, *tail*, *elem* and *null* (No pattern matching either). So my question is: is there a better solution where I only have one function, myreverse, that consumes only one list? (That meets the requirements above, of course)

Thanks!

Comment: Yep. And what I have will get me a full mark. I just want to know if there's a more elegant way to do it, given the above requirements.

Comment: You are also using `(:)`, but it's not on the list of allowed functions ;-)

Comment: Yeah, there's a lot of ways to do it but the constraints make it harder to come up with a nice function. :)

Comment: It is not solvable, because none of tail, elem, head and null  result in a list that is of same type and at least as long as one of the arguments. But the result must be a list of same type and with same length as the argument. Q.E.D.

Comment: @pat: `(:)` is not really a function but a type constructor, so it should be ok ;)

Comment: @sth `(:)` is a data constructor, not a type constructor.  Its type is `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]`, so it is logically a function due to its type containing at least one arrow.  The wikipedia page on [algebraic data types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) describes a data constructor as being somewhat similar to a function, but then in the next sentence says that it is logically a function.  Of course, if we want to have any hope of solving the problem, we have to allow its use!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for anyone who might be interested, this is what I ended up writing:

```
myreverse :: [a] -> [a]
myreverse list = myflip list []
    where myflip list newList = if null list then newList
                                else myflip (tail list) ((head list):newList)
```

Thanks everyone for your comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 7):

You can try reversing a list using `foldl` like so:

```
reverse' :: [a] -> [a]  
reverse' = foldl (\acc x -> x : acc) []
```

Comment: Or the slightly fancier `foldl (flip (:)) []`

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't meet the requirements. :

Comment: @Sadiq  `reverse' sNew = foldl (flip (:)) sNew` takes 2 lists and returns the reversed string.

Keep in mind that Haskell always returns a new value.  I don't know why you would ever need to pass in a value for holding your new result.  Immutable languages don't suffer from the same dangers as imperative ones.

Answer (score 2):

save this in reverse.hs file

```
 reverseString :: [Char] -> [Char]
 reverseString [] = []
 reverseString (x:xs) = reverseString xs ++ [x]
```

then run 
reverseString "abc"

> cba

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the adjustments necessary to meet your additional requirements, your function is equivalent to the way `reverse` [is implemented in GHC](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-List.html#reverse). Therefore I'd assume your function is pretty good the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

This function fulfills your requirements, but is horrible inefficient:

```
rev xs = if null xs then xs else rev (tail xs) ++ [head xs]
```

Your solution isn't bad at all. After using pattern matching and making `myFlip` a local function it wouldn't look ugly. And the technique of using a local function with an accumulator is very common (although not in such easy cases).

Comment: I thought about that one but unfortunately, the ++ operator doesn't meet the requirements. :( Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @Uqi: Then write your own `++`: `app xs ys = if null xs then ys else head xs : app (tail xs) ys`